# Inserting an array saved in a text file into Python numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a text file containing a huge array: 200 rows by 12 columns.
I want to insert this array into python and turn it into a numpy array, where I can perform functions such as 'mean' on it. Here is my code and in the end you see the result, which is an empty array:

```
import numpy as np

reader = open (r"C:\Users\...\Array.txt")
array = reader.read()

for i in array:
    conc_array = np.array(i)
​
>>> print(conc_array)
array(']', dtype='<U1')
```

Comment: How is your array formatted in the txt file?

Comment: have try numpy.loadtxt?

Comment: It might be helpful to show the contents of `array`

Comment: something like this:
[4.561 6.999 4.331 4.561 6.999 5.154 4.331 4.561 6.999 5.154 1.086 2.927
 3.748 7.153 1.797 6.786 2.589 1.389 1.389 2.649 1.797 4.119 2.85  0.841
 0.442 1.899 1.389 0.751 1.511 1.797 5.204 1.768 6.786 1.086 6.923 2.977
...

Comment: Looks like someone just wrote the `str` format of an array to the file.  That format is not intended for conversion back into an array.  The equivalent for a list can be `eval`, but this is missing the commas.  Also it may have '...', skipped data (in which case conversion is hopeless).

Comment: @hpaulj yes that's true. I created this file by using `print(x,y,file)`. So now all of these are strings instead of numbers. Can I do something now?

Comment: Use python string methods to split it into individual number strings, and apply `int` or `float`.  In other words los of basic python processing.